# How to redirect output of shell commands to a file using a C++ program

Tags: unix

I have been asked to implement a shell of my own that works similar to that in the UNIX system.I am having confusion regarding how to implement I/O redirection.

I am able to run some basic commands like "ls" and "cat" using my program.

It would be of great help, if someone can guide me with the "how-to's" of the required problem.I have no clue where to start from.

Answer (score 0):

> I have no clue where to start from.

Start from reading about [`dup2()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html). For just redirecting output or input, there's not much about it.
To redirect standard output to file descriptor *ofd*, call `dup2(ofd, 1)`, to redirect standard input from file descriptor *ifd*, call `dup2(ifd, 0)`, each just before you *run some basic command*.